# Ruby on Rails, before_filter and prepend_before_filter ordering is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, before-filter

In the following example,

```
before_filter :foo
before_filter :bar
before_filter :wah
prepend_before_filter :heehee
prepend_before_filter :haha
```

so then the execution orders will be:

```
haha, heehee, foo, bar, wah?   <-- note that haha is actually before heehee
```

And is there a reason not to list `haha` and `heehee` first in the first place but actually use `prepend`?

Answer (score 27):

To my knowledge this is to solve class inheritance where you cannot define the order of the before_filter:

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  before_filter :do_this_first    
  #....
end

SomeController < ApplicationController    
  before_filter :do_this_second
  #.... 
end
```

Here, neither of the methods defined will have preference unless you use a prepend_before_filter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `prepend_filter`, in a queue of `before_filter`s, it adds a filter in front of the queue. Hence, last come, first served.